# Is there a one-liner to tell vim/ctags autocompletion to search from the middle of a word?

Tags: vim, ctags

In vim (in Insert mode, after running exuberant ctags), I am using `ctrl-x` followed by `ctrl-]` to bring up a dropdown of various possible words/tokens. It's a great feature.

The problem is that by default, this list starts with a bunch of numeric options and automatically inserts the first numeric option, and if I backspace to get rid of the numbers and start typing a part of a word fresh -- with the idea of searching from the middle of the word -- the autocompletion behavior exits entirely.

I know I could type the first letter of the word that I want, then go from there. But that assumes that I know the first letter of the word, which is not necessarily a given.

For example, if I'm working on a pair-programming project with a friend during a long weekend, I might not remember at any given moment whether he called his method promoteRecordStatus(), updateRecordStatus() or boostRecordStatus(). In this example, I would like to type RecordStatus and get the relevant result, which does not seem to be possible at a glance with the current behavior.

So with that scenario in mind: **Is there a simple, vim-native way to tell the editor to start its autocompletion without any assumptions, then search all available tokens for my typed string in all parts of each token?**

I will of course consider plugin suggestions helpful, but I would prefer a short, vim-native answer that doesn't require any plugins if possible. Ideally, the configuration could be set using just a line or two.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in completions all require a match at the starting position. In some cases, you could drop separator characters from the `'iskeyword'` option (e.g. in Vimscript, drop `#` to be able to complete individual components from `foo#bar#BazFunction()`), but this won't work for `camelCaseWords` at all.

Custom `:help complete-functions` can implement any completion search, though. To be based on the tags database, it would have to use `taglist()` as a source, and filter according to the completion base entered before triggering the completion. If you do not anchor this pattern match at the beginning, you have your desired completion.